# why 'onBindViewHolder' Overrides Nothing Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Please help me, I can't implement `onBindViewHolder` in my RecyclerView in Kotlin. I want to make an adapter for my data cards using Reyclerview in Kotlin language android studio. But when I implement `onBindViewHolder` my code throws an error. Please help.

```
package com.brid.azis.vipgame.test.Adapter

import android.content.Context
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import com.brid.azis.vipgame.R
import com.brid.azis.vipgame.test.DataModel.DataCard

class MissionViewAdapter(private val context: Context, private val cards:List<DataCard>):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) =
          CardViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_mission,parent,false))

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = cards.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CardViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindCards(cards[position])
    }

    class CardViewHolder(view:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

        val judul = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_judulkartu)
        val petunjuk = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_petunjukkartu)
        val tanggal = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_tanggalmasukkartu)

        fun bindCards(cards:DataCard) {
            judul.text = cards.judul
            petunjuk.text = cards.petunjuk
            tanggal.text = cards.tanggal
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the error:**

[image: This is the error]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just change this line

```
class MissionViewAdapter(private val context: Context, private val cards:List<DataCard>):
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
```

to

```
class MissionViewAdapter(private val context: Context, private val cards:List<DataCard>):
RecyclerView.Adapter<MissionViewAdapter.CardViewHolder>() {
```

Actually, you are using the main `ViewHolder` class of RecyclerView. That's why your parameters are wrong of `bindViewHolder` method and you are getting that error. In this case, your `onBindViewHolder` method should look like this:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
```